# mongo node driver object reference

Tags: api, node.js, mongodb

In order to write an app handling the database responses I need to know the possible structures and values of the ubiquitous error parameter.

all the callbacks have:

function(err, res) ...

Does anyone know about the structure of the err object?

Answer (score 1):

When provided to the callback, the `err` parameter contains an [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)-based object.  The `name` property of the object can be used to differentiate the types of errors, and the `message` property contains a string description of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $err is usually a string type. See http://jp.wiki.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Error+Handling+in+Mongo+Drivers